# Hazelcast Snowcast sequence generator epoch and id length

Tags: hazelcast

I'm going to use Snowcast https://github.com/noctarius/snowcast as a unique ID generator for my application. I'm going to expose these IDs within a web application urls.

Right now I have a two options how to configure Snowcast sequencer with my Spring Boot application:

```
@Bean
public SnowcastSequencer snowcastSequencer(Snowcast snowcast) {
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2017, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 1, 0, 0);
    SnowcastEpoch snowcastEpoch = SnowcastEpoch.byTimestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

    return snowcast.createSequencer("sequence_generator", snowcastEpoch);
}
```

or

```
@Bean
public SnowcastSequencer snowcastSequencer(Snowcast snowcast){
    SnowcastEpoch snowcastEpoch = SnowcastEpoch.byTimestamp(new Date().getTime());

    return snowcast.createSequencer("sequence_generator", snowcastEpoch);
}
```

as a result of `snowcastSequencer.next()` method invocation in case of `Calendar` based epoch I'm getting a following long value:

```
15617925960433665
```

but in case of `Date` based epoch:

```
12046041089
```

I'm more interested in a shorter IDs.. like the second one but I'm worry about IDs possible uniqueness issue.

Could you please tell or is it okay to use epoch based on Date in case of unique IDs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how those numbers are generated you'll see that there is not shorter or longer ID, as a single ID consists of multiple parts. The timestamp is just one of them. That said the IDs will change over the course of time, as the offset to the epoch (the first few bits) will increase. At some point the long's value will switch over to negative values from the point of Java since all bits are used (even the highest bit) and it'll start to look negative (or you need to print it as unsigned long, put it into a biginteger).

Anyhow that said, there is no such thing as short or longer but it depends on the epoch offset (how many millis have passed since the begin of the epoch) and the number of nodes / IDs in a single millisecond.

PS: in the case of just generating unique IDs over the course of the apps runtime both is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Right now I have to think or it is okay to have a negative values at my urls..

Comment: is there any way to avoid negative values generation ? My solution can't accept negative values ((

Comment: No I'm sorry it is not possible, as the top-most bit is used for epoch millis and that way there's always the possibility to have negative values.